# Is there a "direct" proof of the Galois symmetry on centre of group algebra?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $n$ an integer coprime to $|G|$. Then we have the following map, which is clearly not a morphism of groups in general: $$g\mapsto g^n.$$

This induces a linear automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[G]^G$, the algebra of $G$-invariant functions on $G$ under convolution, and surprisingly, this induced map is also an algebra automorphism, as can be seen by passing to $\mathbb{C}$ and noting that this is the Galois action on characters, which permutes the set of primitive idempotents of this algebra.

My question is whether this surprising fact can be explained directly, without using character theory? I would be interested in both a high-concept explanation of this symmetry, or a generators and relations argument for why there exists, for any $g,h$ in $G$, an $a,b\in G$ with: $$(gh)^n=ag^n a^{-1}bh^n b^{-1}.$$

Comment: Is the quoted equality about $(g h)^n$ true, but you don't know how to prove it, or you're not sure if it's true?

Comment: Its true, and follows from the fact that $g\mapsto g^n$ is an algebra automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[G]^G$, by expanding the product of the classes of $g$ and $h$. I don't know of a non character theoretic proof of why this map is actually an algebra automorphism however.

Comment: There is a theory of products and powers of conjugacy classes; see [Beltrán, Felipe, and Melchor - Some problems about products of conjugacy classes in finite groups](https://dx.doi.org/10.22108/ijgt.2019.111448.1480) for what appears to be a recent survey.  It seems to be in a different direction, but I wonder if that might be the place to look.

Comment: Wow, that's a beautiful find. I am getting a slightly cohomological whiff from it (as, e.g., in the proof of the transfer's homomorphism property).

Comment: Basic question: What is an example of a finite group $G$ and an integer $n$ prime to $|G|$ such that there is no automorphism of $G$ which induces the permutation $\text{Conj}(g) \mapsto \text{Conj}(g^n)$ on conjugacy classes?

Comment: The Frobenius group of order $20$ is an example, trivial outer automorphism group, with nonrational characters, take $n=3$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Note the assumption $\gcd(n, |G|) = 1$. So if $g^n = 1$, then $g = 1$.

Comment: @spin ah, thanks

Comment: There are a number of similar facts which seem non-obvious from a group-theoretic point of view, but are easy to prove with characters: for example, the number of times $ x \in G$ is expressible as a commutator is unchanged if we replace $x$ by a different generator of  $\langle x \rangle.$

Comment: A slightly different (but definitely character theoretic) proof of this interesting fact uses the structure constants $a_{KLM}=\frac{|K||L|}{|G|}\sum_{\chi\in\mathrm{Irr}(G)}\frac{\chi(x_K)\chi(x_L)\overline{\chi(x_M)}}{\chi(1)}.$ If $K^\prime$ etc. are the classes containing the respective $n^{th}$ powers and if $\sigma$ is Chris' automorphism then $a_{K^\prime L^\prime M^\prime}=\frac{|K||L|}{|G|}\sum_{\chi\in\mathrm{Irr}(G)}\frac{\chi^\sigma(x_K)\chi^\sigma(x_L)\overline{\chi^\sigma(x_M)}}{\chi(1)}=a_{KLM}^\sigma,$ so $a_{K^\prime L^\prime M^\prime}=a_{KLM}^\sigma=a_{KLM}.$

Comment: What do you mean by "a generators-and-relations argument for... $(gh)^n=ag^na^{-1}bh^nb^{-1}$"? I doubt there exist such $a,b$ in the free group over $g,h$. For $n=2$ there are none: any $x,y,z$ in a free group satisfying $x^2y^2=z^2$ must commute (it follows there are none whenever $n$ is even).

Comment: By a generators and relations argument I would think some symbolic argument that holds in any torsion group of exponent coprime to $n$, building $a,b$ from $g,h$ using these assumptions and the assumed $n$th root function. If one could give a group of this type where the result fails, it would rule out such an argument, which would also be very interesting.